# Execute the next query based on whether or not this query succedded?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I am making a simple web app. In one part of it, I want a to execute a SQL Query, which is a select query. Now there is a big probablity that the query will fail because no rows will satisfy the given conditions.

Depending upon whether or not the query failed, I want to execute another query.

No matter what I do, I am finding that the first query is getting executed, what's wrong?

Here is the code snippet:

```
$select_query = "SELECT COUNT(*) from entryDetails WHERE user_id='$user_id' and list='$entry->list' and pos='$entry->pos' and monthyearkey='$entry->monthyearkey' and day='$entry->day'";
        if(!mysql_query($select_query))
            $addday_query="INSERT INTO entryDates (user_id, list, pos, monthyearkey, day) VALUES ('$user_id','$entry->list','$entry->pos','$entry->monthyearkey','$entry->day')";
        else
            $addday_query = "UPDATE entryDates SET active=IF(active=1, 0, 1) WHERE user_id='$user_id' and list='$entry->list' and monthyearkey='$entry->monthyearkey' and day='$entry->day'";
        mysql_query($addday_query);
```

The 'IF' condition is always evaluating to true, what's wrong? What should I do? What's the correct way to solve this issue?

Comment: you need to check if any rows are returned, currently you are checking to see if the query succeed, which it did as it has no errors in it.

Comment: First off, don't use `mysql_`. Use PDO or `mysqli_` with prepared statements. Second, you seem to have a gaping security hole in your code. My user ID is `' or true --`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first query is always the one executed, since the select does not actually fail. It simply returns the value 0.

You'll need to fetch the first row, and read out the value, to determine the number of rows found:

```
$result = mysql_query($select_query);
$row = mysql_fetch_row($result);
if($row[0] > 0) { /* At least 1 row found, execute UPDATE */ }
else { /* No rows found, execute INSERT */ }
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php 

    $select_query = "SELECT COUNT(*) from entryDetails WHERE user_id='$user_id' and list='$entry->list' and pos='$entry->pos' and monthyearkey='$entry->monthyearkey' and day='$entry->day'";

    if($result = mysql_query($select_query)){
        if($num_rows = mysql_num_rows($result)){
            $addday_query = "UPDATE entryDates SET active=IF(active=1, 0, 1) WHERE user_id='$user_id' and list='$entry->list' and monthyearkey='$entry->monthyearkey' and day='$entry->day'";
        } else {
            $addday_query="INSERT INTO entryDates (user_id, list, pos, monthyearkey, day) VALUES ('$user_id','$entry->list','$entry->pos','$entry->monthyearkey','$entry->day')";
        }
        mysql_query($addday_query);
    }

?>
```